# Applying font family to six elements - refuses to apply to two and no idea why .

Tags: jquery, css, fonts

I am applying a custom font to all the text in six separate spans. It applies fine to four of them, and not to two of them. I cannot see any difference between them to cause this.

HTML (yes, no spans yet, bear with me):

```
    <body>
        <div id="deepBackground">
            <p id="nav">Websites Blog Plugins Games Resources Apps</p>
        <div id="background"></div>
        </div>        
    </body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    color: #FFFFCC;
    font-family: 'Andika', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
html, body {
    background-color: #330033;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#background {
   background-color: black;
   background-image: url("star.svg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   border: solid;
   border-color: #333333;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border-width: 10px;  
   height: 400px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto; 
   width: 400px;
}

#deepBackground {
   background-color: #330033;
   border: solid;
   border-color: #333333;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border-width: 10px;
   height: 500px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   margin-top: 10%;
   width: 500px;   
}

#nav {    
    height: 40px;
}

p span {
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: bottom center;
}

.word1 {   
    transform: translateX(-42px); 
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-42px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   -ms-transform: translateX(-42px); /* IE 9 */
}

.word2 { 
    transform: rotate(60deg) translateY(20px); 
   -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) translateY(20px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   -ms-transform: rotate(60deg) translateY(20px); /* IE 9 */
}

.word3 {
   transform: rotate(120deg) translateY(30px); 
   -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) translateY(30px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   -ms-transform: rotate(120deg) translateY(30px); /* IE 9 */
}

.word4 {
   transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(30px); 
   -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(30px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(30px); /* IE 9 */
  }

.word5 {  
   transform: rotate(240deg) translateY(-30px); 
   -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg) translate(10px,-30px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   -ms-transform: rotate(240deg) translateY(-30px); /* IE 9 */
}

.word6 {
   transform: rotate(300deg) translateY(-20px); 
   -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) translateY(-20px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
   -ms-transform: rotate(300deg) translateY(-20px); /* IE 9 */
}
```

It's .word1 and .word4 that are failing to pick up the font styling. I am working in chrome.

The spans are generated by calling 'lettering()' on #nav (see js below)

I have tried:

- putting the font-family definition in .word1, in #deepBackground and in html,body
- messing around with whether they have translate and/or rotate in there . . . but all the others do   too and are fine.
- googling

Interestingly, I have some jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#nav").lettering('words');

$("[class^=word]").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css({"color": "red", "font-weight": "900"});
});

$("[class^=word]").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css({"color": "#FFFFCC", "font-weight": "400"});
});
});
```

During mouseover the font is applied correctly, but then reverts once you mouse out.

Any ideas?

Comment: please let us see this live so we can examine it. atleast a jsbin would help.

Comment: Persuading the lettering API I'm using (to split the words and try and make them go all circular . . ) to work in jsfiddle doesn't seem to be happening . . . may have to just do a slight rebuild without the plugin and see if that works . . .